# cannot knit PDF in R studio

Tags: r, pdf, knitr

I am totally new to RStudio and I was working on an RMarkdown document. When I click on `Knit PDF`, and I keep getting the result like this:

> output file: A1-soln-template__2__molly.knit.md
>
> ! Package inputenc Error: Unicode char μ (U+3BC)
>
> (inputenc)                not set up for use with LaTeX.
>
> See the inputenc package documentation for explanation.
>
> Type  H   for immediate help.
>
> ...
>   l.142 null hypothesis: Ho:μ
>
> Try running pandoc with --latex-engine=xelatex.
>
> pandoc: Error producing PDF
>
> Error: pandoc document conversion failed with error 43
>
> Execution halted

How can I solve this and get things to work?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
install.packages('jsonlite', dependencies=TRUE, repos='http://cran.rstudio.com/')
```

Also, you might need to install [MiKTeX](http://miktex.org/2.9/setup).

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is related to encoding. You are trying to include ASCII characters where they should not be.

In particular, you have typed:

> Ho:μ

This needs to be changed to:

```
$H_0: \mu$
```

You will need to learn some [LaTeX](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).