# I have unicode characters/ latex errors in my documentation causing issues in R CMD check. How do I troubleshoot?

Tags: r, package, latex, devtools, roxygen2

I am building my my first pacakge, and when running `R CMD check` after `devtools::build()` I found a bunch of issues with "checking PDF version of the manual." I struggled to find directions on how to troubleshoot so I'm going to ask this question: "How can I identify the problematic text in my .R files that Roxygen uses to make the .Rd files that make up the manual?" and then go ahead an answer in hopes that it is useful to someone else down the line.

I would get a long series of WARNINGS, and the unique components are below:

> LaTeX errors when creating PDF version.
> This typically indicates Rd problems.
> LaTeX errors found:
> ! LaTeX Error: Bad math environment delimiter.
>
> See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation. Type  H
>   for immediate help.
> ! Package inputenc Error: Unicode character ℓ (U+2113) (inputenc)
> not set up for use with LaTeX.
>
> See the inputenc package documentation for explanation. Type  H
>   for immediate help.

I thought these were pretty clear: Somewhere I have bad Latex (like a missing curly bracket or dollar sign, a imagine), and also there is some issue with including this unicode character.

My question is, "How do I identify the offending lines?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following up on @user2554330's comment. Here's a simple way to check for eventual unicode characters in your functions and documentation:

```
# functions
functions <- list.files(path = './R', all.files = T, recursive = T, full.names = T)
lapply(X=functions, FUN = tools::showNonASCIIfile)
```

```
# documentation
docs <- list.files(path = './man', all.files = T, recursive = T, full.names = T)
lapply(X=docs, FUN = tools::showNonASCIIfile)
```

Answer (score 0):

Running `R CMD check` produces a directory, mypackagename.Rcheck/

In my case there is a file in there called Rdlatex.log

This logfile has more verbose (and very helpful/ clear) warning and error messages with line numbers and file names to allow me to find the offending text and develop some ideas of how to fix it :-)

There may be other issues (e.g. I noticed in other [related](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39939775/8400969) questions the suggestion to check the installation and paths for the underlying latex infrastructure), but it seems like starting with my .R files is likely to be fruitful.

Comment: You can also take advantage of the `tools::showNonASCIIfile()` function to find locations in the original `*.R` files.

Answer (score 0):

This is platform-specific but I'm pretty sure there are text editors equivalent on other platforms.

On MacOSX I use  BareBones Edit, and it has some commands like "Zap Gremlins" which eliminate all non-ASCII characters and/or optionally replace things like 'smart quotes' with ASCII quote characters.

As to fixing LaTeX embedded command strings:  best I can suggest is using some tool like "KLatexFormula" (Windows) or equivalent to play with the strings until they render.

Comment: Thanks for these tips! I noticed you say to eliminate "non-ASCII characters"... is the general recommendation then to avoid them? I had hoped to include U+2113 $\ell$ in my documentation... is that a no-no?

Comment: Maybe the answer is that equations  should be represented twice! Once in latex and a second time in ASCII: https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-exts.html#Mathematics